# Create reusable MUI Text field component with use of react hook form in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying too create a reusable MUI text field component  and use it in across the project. I like to get best approach for this . below is my code what I am written . please let me know what is best approach

Here i created a one common component for textinput using material ui and used in my components. for validation using yup

**TextInput.tsx**

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { TextInputProps } from './TextInput.type';

interface TextInputProps {
  label: string | React.ReactNode;
  name: string;
  control: any;
  defaultValue?: string;
  helperText?: string;
  variant?: 'outlined' | 'standard' | 'filled';
  required?: boolean;
  error?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  multiline?: boolean;
  maxRows?: number;
  fullWidth?: boolean;
}

export const TextInput: FC<TextInputProps> = ({
  name,
  control,
  label,
  fullWidth = false
}) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
        <TextField
          sx={{
            input: {
              background: theme.palette.common.white
            },
            '& .MuiFilledInput-root': {
              background: theme.palette.common.white,
              borderRadius: 1,
              height: 50,
              border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.grey[300]}`,
              '&:hover': {
                background: theme.palette.common.white
              }
            }
          }}
          helperText={error ? error.message : null}
          size="small"
          error={!!error}
          onChange={onChange}
          value={value}
          label={label}
          variant="filled"
          fullWidth={fullWidth}
          InputProps={{
            disableUnderline: true
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

**Mycomponent.tsx**

```
import { Button, Paper, Typography, Stack } from '@mui/material';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { TextInput } from 'src/components/formControls/textInput';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

interface IFormInput {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
}

const defaultValues = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  age: ''
};
const validationSchema: any = Yup.object().shape({
  firstName: Yup.string().required('Please enter first name'),
  lastName: Yup.string().required('Please enter last name'),
  age: Yup.number()
    .typeError('Please enter valid age')
    .required('required filed')
});
export const Forms = () => {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    control,
    formState: { isDirty }
  } = useForm<any>({
    defaultValues: defaultValues,
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema)
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: IFormInput) => console.log(data);
  console.log('isDirty', isDirty);
  return (
    <Paper>
      <Typography variant="h4"> Form Demo</Typography>
      <Stack spacing={6} sx={{ width: '50%' }} p={6}>
        <TextInput name="firstName" control={control} label="First name" />
        <TextInput name="lastName" control={control} label="Last name" />
        <TextInput name="age" control={control} label="Age" />
        <Button
          onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          variant={'contained'}
          disabled={!isDirty}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={() => reset()} variant={'outlined'}>
          Reset
        </Button>
      </Stack>
    </Paper>
  );
};
```